# NPGSQL select query intermittently returns no rows

Tags: postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I am running a simple select query thusly:

```
Private Function ReturnTableQuery(ByVal SQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rs As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim Adapter As NpgsqlDataAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter

    Try
        If conn Is Nothing Then
            ConnectDatabase()
        End If
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            ConnectDatabase()
        End If
        Adapter.SelectCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(SQL, conn)
        Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
        Adapter.Fill(rs)
    Catch ex As Exception
        PreserveStackTrace(ex)
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return rs

End Function
```

The SQL command is:

```
Select id, application, datetimestamp, status, data, attemptcount from queue where application='reportengine' and status=4 and datetimestamp <= now()  order by datetimestamp limit 1
```

I sometimes get 0 rows returned.

If I run the exact same query in pgAdmin while it is failing in my program, it returns a row as expected.

If I close and re-open the connection it works, but I can't determine if there is anything wrong with the connection beforehand.

I could just re-open the connection every time, but I would rather not recreate the connection as often as I would need to.

I am also getting intermittent errors like "unknown server response" which I am catching and re-opening the connection.

Any ideas why the connection is so fragile and is there an inexpensive way to check the ***actual*** connection status?

Thx,
Brad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sharing your connection between multiple threads? Npgsql, as other data providers,  is not thread safe. I would rank this is the most probable cause of your problems. You should open a connection, use it and then close it. That's the most scalable pattern when using a connection pool. I hope it helps.

Comment: You are correct! This is not my first multi-threaded app using npgsql, but this time I am indeed trying to share a connection between threads via a shared class. I will refactor.